# Logistic Regression - Two Dependent variables not playing well with each other

Tags: regression, logistic, multicollinearity

My name is Abhi and I trying to teach myself logistic regression by solving some of the problems available on the internet. I am using R and RStudio as the development environment

***Problem Statement***

Given the age, sex, class(first,second,third), ticket_id for each passenger can you predict if he survived or died when the titanic sank.

Assume passengers in first class are more likely to survive. Assume passengers in certain areas of the boat (those near to part which hit the iceberg) are more likely to perish. I ran logistic regression for both these variables independently.

**Here are my results for passenger class**

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4390  -0.7569  -0.7569   0.9367   1.6673  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.44679    0.20743   6.975 3.06e-12 ***
Pclass      -0.85011    0.08715  -9.755  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1186.7  on 890  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1084.4  on 889  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1088.4
```

**Here are my results for Ticket Id**

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2624  -0.8909  -0.7040   1.0947   1.7415  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.19769    0.09974   1.982   0.0475 *  
Ticket2     -0.91681    0.22155  -4.138  3.5e-05 ***
Ticket3     -1.46620    0.16052  -9.134  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1186.7  on 890  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1094.0  on 888  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1100

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

However when I add both passenger class & ticket id to the formula I dont get the results that I am expecting. It seems that both the features are cancelling each other out

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4431  -0.8649  -0.6772   0.9332   1.7806  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.1713     0.2171   5.396 6.80e-08 ***
Pclass       -0.5654     0.1110  -5.094 3.50e-07 ***
Ticket2      -0.4361     0.2421  -1.801   0.0716 .  
Ticket3      -0.8311     0.2033  -4.089 4.33e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1186.7  on 890  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1067.8  on 887  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1075.8
```

I ran the vif test on both these features & they do not seem to be collinear. What am I missing here? If both these features give great results separately why dont they give good results when used together.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What results were you expecting? What do you mean by "cancelling each other out"? Why are these results not good?

Comment: Collinearity is almost never an all-or-nothing phenomenon.  There must be some collinearity in order for coefficients to change the way you have shown.  Try this simulation.  Create a variable that is similar to Pclass but a little less strongly associated with ticket_id than Pclass is.  Then run an analysis like the one above and see what happens to the progression of coefficients.  Then try it again with even less of an association.

Comment: @NickStauner I was expecting to get much better values of AIC when I used both passenger class & ticket id in the model. It seems that there is covariance between passenger class & ticket id but I get very small values for gvif (1.59)